# Software integrating YouTube, Netflix, Quora, and Wikipedia

Tags: video, video-editing, social-networks, video-player, video-recording

I am looking for a container app for smartphones (and computers) which embeds videos from YouTube at the top (or, from whatever video service, Vimeo, Netflix, or even its own videos), and at the bottom has a divider which can be dragged up and down with at the top quora questions and answers relative to the video and at the bottom Wikipedia articles relative to the video.

The video outputs the text of the words spoken by the actors as well as descriptions of objects appearing, and feeds these as extracted from the service for extracting such words, into quora, and Wikipedia, which, run their own services. And, then, displays the three together.

So, for this to work, YouTube or whatever video service and its videos need to support providing the textual descriptions as a service (for YouTube and video services) as programmer interfaces, and the video makers need to embed these in the video (which also means the video file format must be designed to support this).

Quora and Wikipedia must run on the web in modes that can be queried, programmatically (if not via the web, then via a service).

The integration of these three software components would be ideal for studying the details of a video or through its details, and, pausing the video as you watch it, and the descriptive content from quora and Wikipedia changes, seven seconds in a go at a time, and the user can pause the video to view.

For instance, when watching Superman, you can pause to view what a laser or infrared beam is when the laser comes out of the eyes, or you can look up gravitational force when Superman flies around the earth (pausing, the video, on the smartphone, in each case (to read the content, and study it (with all the motivation from the video)).

Or when a person dies and the video displays worms in it, you can read the pertaining video from Wikipedia that displays how worms are used in fornisic science with dead bodies.

Videos not embedding this information, can be converted and annotated by amateur users, to convey this information in the annotations.

Where not annotated, the technology from Google Lens could be used to tell the Quora and Wikipedia service what's in the video (and display the results below, as the video plays).

I would be very glad if some software giant or some amateur programmers implemented this, perhaps getting in touch with Quora, Wikipedia, YouTube, Netflix, etc... (in order to achieve this).

I would be willing to pay a monthly subscription fee (as per using the service with all, instead, of just a few, videos).

Where can I find such software?

Thank you for your help, effort, and getting in touch with whom you can get in touch to get this done

If this software exists, please let me know.

Thanks.